# MediaStore: How can I get other apps to recognize my files?

Tags: android, mediastore

I have an app named Intonia originally written for older versions of Android.  It records audio, and saves .wav or .mp3 files in a local directory.  The directory name is based on `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, which on my Pixel 5 phone evaluates to `/storage/emulated/0/Intonia`.

I'm trying to upgrade my app to the new requirements for Android 11 by using the MediaStore API.  I've been pretty much successful in finding music files in other places.  But I'm frustrated in making my files visible to other apps.

When I download any music player app (I've tried several) from the Play Store, it recognizes an "Album" named Intonia.  However the album contains only some of the files in the Intonia directory.  I can't see any pattern on which files get reflected in the music player app and which don't.  After I write a new file, calling `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` and/or `ContentResolver.insert` doesn't seem to have any effect on these other apps.

I'm confused about the relationship between the MediaStore and the underlying file structure.  How do the two relate?  There must be something very fundamental I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's nothing wrong with my code.  The problem lies with the music player apps I downloaded.  They will not display short sound clips.  On some of them the duration limit is settable, on at least one other it's fixed at 30 seconds.  Since I was using short files to test file discovery, it only appeared that my files weren't making it into the MediaStore database.